# Detect changes in the value of shiny inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where I would like to get the change in a select input compared to the last selection.

For example in this app, three months are initially selected. `January February March`
If a user selects `April`, I would like to see the change between the initial selection and the current selection.

```
**Initial selection:**
January February March

**Current selection:**
January February March April
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    
    selectInput("months", label = "Select Months", 
                choices = c(month.name[]), selected = month.name[1:3], 
                multiple = TRUE)),
  
  strong("Initial selection:"), textOutput("initial_selection"), br(),
  strong("Current selection:"), textOutput("current_selection")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ## Initial selection (should stay the same for one additional change)
  output$initial_selection <- renderText({ input$months })
  
  ## Current selection (after the change)
  output$current_selection <- renderText({ input$months })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried a few random methods but with no success. Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I am going to create a counter in the
`reactiveValues` so we can monitor the changes, first when it is 0, we shall record the initial selections, then we can use the counter for the new changes...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    
    selectInput("months", label = "Select Months", 
                choices = c(month.name[]), selected = month.name[1:3], 
                multiple = TRUE)),
  
  strong("Initial selection:"), textOutput("initial_selection"), br(),
  strong("Current selection:"), textOutput("current_selection")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(count = 0,initial_selection = NULL,current_selection=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$months,{
    if(v$count==0){
      v$initial_selection <- input$months
      v$current_selection <- input$months
    }else{
      v$current_selection <- input$months
    }
    v$count <- v$count + 1
  })
  

  ## Initial selection (should stay the same for one additional change)
  output$initial_selection <- renderText({
    v$initial_selection
  })
  
  ## Current selection (after the change)
  output$current_selection <- renderText({ 
    v$current_selection 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect... so nice of you. Thanks!!! I've never used reactiveValues function before...

Comment: I wonder if updating the initial value with each new selection is possible in the way that it is only one step behind the current value. For example, the initial value becomes the second last of the current value?
In other words, initial selection is always one step behind current selection.